# Find when user has scrolled to the end of a given table

Tags: jquery

How do I find out if a user has scrolled to the end of a table using jQuery?  I can find when the user scrolls to the end of a page using this:

```
if( document.body.scrollHeight - $( window ).scrollTop()  <= $( window ).height() ) {
  // do something
}
```

but how do I do this with a table e.g. `$(#table-name)` ?

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var $table = $("#table-name");

    if ($table.position().top + $table.height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        console.log('Reached end of table');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9u8m9/)**

Answer (score 1):

There's also a jquery plugin for this, which encompasses a lot of other functionality:

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($("table")[0].scrollHeight - $(window).scrollTop() <= $(window).height()) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/NesFE/)